# How to make PI calculation program in Akka?

Tags: java, maven, akka

I would like to benchmark the Pi program using Akka framework. I did following this [tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/intro/getting-started-first-java.html). However when I compiled it, it give an error about `can't find symbol` in a lot of code in that tutorial such as `symbol:method shutdown()`, `symbol:class UntypedActorFactory`, and also  `symbol:class RoundRobinPool.`

I also follow the official documentation on the akka website but it still give me the same error.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),please?

Comment: Why the java tag?

Comment: @OleV.V. Because he's probably using the java api of akka

Comment: I solved my problem and yes I use java api of AKKA @thwiegan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the new code from the new akka actor and other libraries version. I think in my version is 2.0 however in my pom.xml file is 2.5.2. So I change my code to newest one according to AKKA document and it's working.